# vagrant synced folder - network error on read

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant-windows

Im having issues with synced folders in vagrant. 
I have a windows 7 host, using virtual box i have a server 2012 guest.
 
The shares mount and i can navigate to to the directory on the guest but when I do a `dir` i get an network error. I can browse to the directory on the guest.  Any ideas?

```
[localhost]: PS C:\Users\Administrator\Documents> dir .\guest_share

dir : The network path was not found.
+ CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (C:\Users\Admini...nts\guest_share:String) [Get-ChildItem], IOException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Creating a file fails with an identical error.
 
I have enabled CredSSP on host and guest. 
I get identical behavior with default syned folder as i get with my custom one.

Here is the excerpt from my vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "share/", "C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/guest_share"
```